# DOM + XML Questions + what is really happening?

Tags: xml, vba, dom

I'm pretty new to XML and DOM. I'm trying to fetch the USD rate from http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml

The code works great right now but I don't really grasp several parts of what's going on.

Questions

- In the XML file I see several "xmlns" tags, I know that these are for namespaces, but I have never encountered a scenario where you have two. When I'm creating my namespace referencer, why it is the last one of the namespaces I use?
- When I'm selecting my nodes, in my opinion to get to the Cube nodes I should use xDOM.selectNodes("/f:gesmes/f:gesmes/f:Cube") but this and any other combination of f:gesmes returns zero(!) nodes. The only way I have been able to access the Cube nodes is by the // expression
- Why does the code not work without Error handling procedures? Without the On Error Resume Next the code spews out a "object variable or with block not set" error

My code

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub run() ' run the whole operation'

Dim http_req As http_req: Set http_req = New http_req
Dim xDom As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Set xDom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

Dim url As String: url = "http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml"
xDom.async = False
xDom.Load url

Do Until xDom.ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
Loop

Call find_ClassElement(xDom)

End Sub

Private Sub find_ClassElement(xDom As MSXML2.DOMDocument60)

Dim ticker As String
Dim if_USD As String

Dim xDOM_element As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
Dim xDOM_attribute As MSXML2.IXMLDOMAttribute
Dim xDom_selection As MSXML2.IXMLDOMSelection
Dim xDOM_nodeList As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

xDom.setProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:f='http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref'"

Set xDOM_nodeList = xDom.SelectNodes("//f:Cube")

For Each xDOM_element In xDOM_nodeList
        On Error Resume Next
        if_USD = xDOM_element.Attributes(0).text
        On Error GoTo 0
        If if_USD = "USD" Then
            ticker = xDOM_element.Attributes(1).text
        End If
        Next
    Debug.Print ticker
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding question #1, nothing special with having multiple namespaces, many XML has it. The namespace without prefix (`xmlns="...."`) is recognized as default namespace. Basically having default namespace, all descendant nodes and the node where default namespace declared inherits the same namespace. Unless a node explicitly use a prefix that points to different namespace URI, or has different default namespace declared locally.

That is the reason why you need to register the `f` prefix and use it for `<Cube>` nodes despite the `<Cube>`s doesn't have prefix or namespace declaration them self (because they inherits default namespace from the parent node `<gesmes:Envelope>`. And the `Envelope` node it self is not in default namespace, because it has `gesmes` prefix).

Regarding question #2, if you look at the XML closely, you'll see that the correct path to inner-most `<Cube>` nodes is as follow  :

```
/gesmes:Envelope/f:Cube/f:Cube/f:Cube
```

..you may need to register `gesmes` namespace prefix (along with the `f` prefix) before using it in the XPath.

Regarding question #3, you can use pure XPath expression to get USD rate in a much cleaner & safer way :

```
//f:Cube[@currency='USD']
```

this XPath tell to return only `<Cube>` nodes having `currency` attribute value equals `USD`.

Comment: +1 I knew there was a better way to get the USD rate using XPath expression.  Good answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a whiz at this but can usually hack my way through it. As I see it the `Cube` node isn't part of the "gesmes" namespace.  That answers #2.

I don't know the answer to your first point, unfortunately.

For #3, that is not how I would handle it but you need a way to handle nodes which have NO attributes, or are otherwise not what you expect. You could instead do:

```
For Each xDOM_element In xDOM_nodeList
    If xDom_Element.attributes.length > 0 Then 
        if_USD = xDOM_element.attributes(0).Text
    Else
        if_USD = ""
    End If

    If if_USD = "USD" Then
        ticker = xDOM_element.Attributes(1).text
    End If
    Debug.Print ticker
Next
```